# Combobox doesn't open inside ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have list view of expanders, each expander contain usercontrol, inside the usercontrol I have combobox, since I added the expander to list the combobox doesn't open, my code looks as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Expanders}"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
  Expander ex = new Expander();
  ex.Content = new MyUserControl();//<-- here there is a combobox
  Expanders = new ObservableCollection<Expander>
  {
     ex 
  };
}

ObservableCollection<Expander> expanders;
public ObservableCollection<Expander> Expanders
{  
    get { return expanders; }
    set
    {
          expanders = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("Expanders");
     }
}
```

I have Comobobox inside the usercontrol, but after I added it to the listview the combobox doesn't open:

[image]

> **EDIT: (The answer)**
>
> I changed to:

```
MyUserControl uc=new MyUserControl();
uc.ItemSource=this;
```

and it worked

Comment: user controls in view models is  *so*  mvvm ...

Comment: @ASh Didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your ObservableCollection is initialized and has Items in it. It seems like your collection is empty and thats why it shows nothing when you expand your combobox.